# parenting not working on certain objects, text turns yellow and creates linked copy instead

Tags: linked-data

When I try to parent certain objects, instead of one moving under the other in the hierarchy now suddenly the child objects stays exactly where it is and the text turns yellow, and there is a second sort-of linked ghost child attached to parent. I have no idea how this happened, must have hit some key accidentally and now I don't even know what to search for since I have no idea what I did and searching for stuff like "cant parent child gets linked instead yellow text" yields absolutely nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, my hierarchy got so complex that I didn't notice I accidentally created the object child outside of the collection the parent is part of. There is no way to spot that easily unless you scroll all the way up through the hierarchy.